# Como inserir dados numa tabela de outro banco somente se nao existir?

Tags: mysql

Gostaria que, ao inserir na tabela Clientes do banco1, fosse inserido na tabela Clientes do banco2, mas só se já não houver.
Atualmente meu codigo está assim:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER trIntegracaoBancos AFTER INSERT
ON banco1.clientes FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM banco2.Clientes) THEN
            INSERT INTO banco2.Clientes (id, nome, dat_nascimento, cpf, rg, endereco, numero, bairro, cidade, estado, cep)
            SELECT id, nome, dat_nascimento, cpf, rg, endereco, numero, bairro, cidade, estado, cep;
    END IF;
END;

$$
```

O if verifica deveria verificar se nao existe.

Comment: " INSERT INTO products (nome, categoria, descricao) VALUES ('Black Join', 'Eletronicos', 'Lorem Ipsum);  " só insere se não existir por padrão se existir ele retorna um erro.

Comment: Descobri a resposta e inseri na publicação, espero que ajude quem tiver as mesmas dúvidas.

Comment: Não edite sua pergunta com resposta. Queira ler o [Tour] e [Help] para entender melhor o site.

Comment: Bacco meu comentario posterior nao era um comentario, e sim uma solução. Deveria ler o conteudo antes de tomar alguma decisão.